# Bezout theorem for germs of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, intersection-theory, local-rings, several-complex-variables

UPDATE.

It was pointed out by @Dmitri that two smooth curves given by $f=y$ and $g=y+x^k$ in $\mathbb C^2$ provide a simple counterexample.

Let $f_1, \ldots, f_p, g_1, \ldots, g_q$ be germs of holomorphic functions at $0$ in $\mathbb C^{p+q}$.
Assume that the multiplicity ${\rm mult}(f_1, \ldots, f_p)$ is finite
let
$$
 V:= \{ f_1 = \ldots = f_p =0\}
$$ 
be (germ of) the zero variety of $f_1, \ldots, f_p$,
and denote by
${\rm mult}_V(g_1, \ldots, g_q)$
the maximum number for points in the fiber of 
the restriction $g|_V$, where
$g:=(g_1, \ldots, g_q)$.

Is the following true?

$$
 {\rm mult}(f_1, \ldots, f_p, g_1, \ldots, g_q)
  \le
 {\rm mult}(f_1, \ldots, f_p)
\cdot
 {\rm mult}_V(g_1, \ldots, g_q)
$$

For example, if $f=y$ and $g=y+x^k$, 
we have ${\rm mult} (f) = {\rm mult} (g) = 1$ but 
${\rm mult}(f, g) = k$. On the other hand, for $V=\{f=0\}$,
we have
${\rm mult}_V (g) = k$, so the above relation is correct.

---

OLD QUESTION (the answer is no).

Is the following local holomorphic variant of Bezout theorem true:

Let $f_1, \ldots, f_p, g_1, \ldots, g_q$ be germs of holomorphic functions at $0$ in $\mathbb C^{p+q}$.
Then
$$
 {\rm mult}(f_1, \ldots, f_p, g_1, \ldots, g_q) = 
 {\rm mult}(f_1, \ldots, f_p)
\cdot
 {\rm mult}(g_1, \ldots, g_q),
\quad (*)
$$
provided the first multiplicity is finite.

Here for $m$ holomorphic germs $(h_1, \dots, h_m)$ in $\mathbb C^n$, $m\le n$, the multiplicity ${\rm mult}(h_1, \ldots, h_m)$ is defined as
the minimum dimension of the quotient 
$$
 \cal O/\langle h_1, \ldots, h_m, l_1, \ldots, l_{n-m} \rangle 
$$
of the ring $\cal O = \cal O_{\mathbb C^n,0}$ of germs at $0$ of holomorphic functions in $\mathbb C^n$ modulo the ideal generated by the germs $h_1, \ldots, h_m, l_1, \ldots, l_{n-m}$, with $l_j$ being linear functions, and the minimum is taken over all choices of the $l_j$.

Equivalently, the multiplicity can be defined as the minimum number of points (over all choices of the linear functions $l_j$) in the preimage of a generic point in $\mathbb C^n$ near $0$ under the map
$$
 z\mapsto (h_1(z), \ldots, h_m(z), l_1(z), \ldots, l_{n-m}(z)),
$$
where the same notation is used for the germ representative functions.
(Instead of taking generic point, one can take the maximal number of points in a preimage.)

Comment: If $\dim \mathcal{O}/(f_1,\ldots, f_p, g_1,\ldots, g_q)$  is finite, where $\mathcal{O}$ is the germs of functions in $\mathbb{C}^n$, then $n\leq p+q$, so I am not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Mohan True, that is why the linear functions $l_j$ are added to the ideal in the definition of the multiplicity.

Comment: Then, adding those linear functions should reduce to the $n=p+q$ case, so I don't still see the issue.

Comment: @Mohan Good point, agree. The 2nd question is equivalent, so I've removed it. Thanks.

Comment: I guess I am missing something, but why $f_1=y$, $g_1=y-x^2$ is not a counter-example in $\mathbb C^2$, since $2\ne 1\cdot 1$? Multiplicity of the intersection of a line and parabola is two, and they are smooth.

Comment: Your example is correct and shows it is false even for $n=p+q$. My contention only was that if true for $n=p+q$ (which is false), it is true for $n\geq p+q$.

Comment: I guess you are making confusion with different types of multiplicity, namely the algebraic multiplicity that counts the vanishing order of the germ and the Milnor number that is the right number for Bezout's theorem.

Comment: @Dmitri Indeed, that seems like a simple counterexample. I have updated the question to a more refined one, that should work for these examples.

Comment: @AlanMuniz Could you provide any reference for the Milnor number in relation with Bezout theorem?